# Why was this "what are the advantages of" question closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582102/why-animate-images-using-javascript-or-css?noredirect=1#comment38080887_24582102) last night, and it was quickly downvoted and closed for being "opinion based". This is a big surprise to me. It's been a while since I've posted questions here, but this actually struck me as a very good question that it was a shame wasn't on the site already.

I don't see how this any more opinion-based than any other question. There are right and wrong answers.

Comment: Seriously? That question is so open ended. Instant vote to close material

Comment: Well.. I participated..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are asking for a list of pros and cons.

And **everyone** has a different opinion on what those are. What one person may see as a pro, another may see as a con.

Opinions. Hence - opinion based.

---

Frankly, I would have gone with overly broad as a close reason.

Asking for lists of things is off-topic as it is not suitable for our Q&A format.

Comment: It's not too late to swing that employee hammer and change the close reason...

Comment: @Cupcake - meh. Closed is closed. And both apply in this case, so, no real point.

Comment: Everyone has a different opinion, but you could say that about any question. I mean, some things objectively *are* pros, and some things objectively *are* cons. The only thing that's opinion based is how you weigh them.

Comment: @JackM - as I said, I would have closed it for another reason. Does it really matter to you which reason was used? The question is overly broad. The problem is that it invites lists - and every person will have a different list. And the separate lists cannot be objectively voted on.